# iOS: How to put a button on the top of SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, storekit

I want to put a custom button on the top of SKStoreProductViewController. I tried it like below but it did not work. I was wondering if you could give me any advices.

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(showShareDialog)];
storeViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;

storeViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:storeViewController animated:YES completion:^() {
    [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:appId}
                                   completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {}];
}];
```